# How to get a django file instance from pyexcelerate workbook?

Tags: python, django, pandas, pyexcelerate

I have recently checked the `pyexcelerate` to help improve the performace of exporting a pandas data frame to excel file i have the following code

```
values = [my_df.columns] + list(my_df.values)
wb = Workbook()
wb.new_sheet('outputs', data=values) 
wb.save('outputfile.xlsx')
```

I have a django model that has a filefield into it how can i save the generated `wb` to a django file field ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Django and pyexcelerate, you can return/download the file with the following:

Import:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
```

In your Django views.py:

```
excel_filename = "example.xlsx"
response = HttpResponse(content_type='xlsx')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment;filename=' + excel_filename
workbook = Workbook()        
sheet1 = workbook.new_sheet("data example", data=data)
workbook.save(response)
return response
```